# Is there alternate open source font for Chevin Light and Chevin Bold?

Tags: font-recommendation, font-licensing, open-source

I am working on XSLT and I have to find an open source Font which might be similar to Chevin Light as well as for Chevin Bold. I am searching manually for two days but I am not getting any closer to the answer and the deadline is approaching near. Does anyone knows any answer to this question or any website which might help me?

The Image below is the font for Chevin light:
[image: Chevin Light]

The image below is the font for Chevin bold:
[image]

If anyone knows the open source alternatives of these fonts then put an answer for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an exact match but a nice free alternative is [Dosis](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Dosis) via Google fonts. It's available in seven weights and, in my opinion, pairs nicely with a wide variety of typefaces.

[image]

Comment: I tried this font, but its a bit long in height than the chevin one. Is there any other alternative. Although your answer opened a new window to my search, could you give some other alternative.

Comment: found out this tool([link](https://tiff.herokuapp.com/)) to compare two fonts. But no success yet.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact match and isn't rounded, but perhaps usable.

[image: Sample of Type faces Exo 2]

You can get Exo 2 at fontlibrary(dot)org - it has a SIL (Open Font) license.

Comment: I used this font too. It's not acceptable. For now we are thinking to buy the license of the chevin fonts. As the client is not accepting even a 1% change.

Comment: Oh well, if there is a client involved, then the only answer is to buy the font. To be fair you did ask for alternatives. It's really too much to expect that an "alternative" be an exact copy of an existing paid-for font. That would be copyright infringement.

Comment: Yeah that's true. But the client said that he will consider the alternatives if they suit him. But we showed him the alternatives and none of them satisfied them. So I think we have to buy the fonts. Yet I had a good learning of fonts as it was my first time playing with them.

Comment: Could someone confirm whether chevin font is a paid font or a free font. Some websites say it's free and provide it for a download. Whereas some say that it has a copyright license. If someone has good knowledge of fonts then please do confirm.

Comment: please follow [link](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92479/how-to-know-whether-a-font-is-paid-or-free) to get an answer to my previous comment.