# How to know whether a font is paid or free?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

This question is an extension of my previous [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87484/is-there-alternate-open-source-font-for-chevin-light-and-chevin-bold). I had used Chevin Light and Chevin Bold in my project after downloading it from a website. Later I came to know that they are licensed fonts and I have to pay to use those fonts.

I referred [fontshop.com](https://www.fontshop.com/families/chevin) to verify that they are paid or not. The problem is that this website is giving an enhanced name for the fonts for example:

- I am using **Chevin Light** and fontshop calls it **Chevin Pro Light**
- I am using **Chevin Bold** and fontshop calls it **Chevin Pro Bold**.

I need to know is there a difference between them or are they same. Altogether I need to know an authentic source where I can know whether a font is free that is open source or paid(licensed).

And if I have to buy a license, then could someone more experienced in the Fonts stuff guide me where should I buy the license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***How to know***: look it up on the internet. Find the font foundry (the designers), visit their website, and check the font licences and availability/pricing options.

In your case, a quick google search reveals the font foundry is G-Type. Their website is here: http://www.g-type.com

***Where to buy***: there are several websites offering licences, and you can even buy it direct from G-Type.

Comment: Are chevin light and chevin pro light same or different. Because I am not getting any info about their distinction.

Comment: This is a good start. Be aware, though, that there are multiple shady websites offering font files for free, while they are just rips of commercial type.

Comment: @Vincent yeah I had already downloaded the font from one of these website, which increased more confusion about the fonts to be licensed or open source.

Comment: Pro versions usually have more things included (more languages, extra characters). Please pay for the font files your are using commercially or use commercially-free fonts like Google Fonts.

Comment: Everyone please check this [URL](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Chevin-Light) it provides chevin light font. Which is making me think that it might be possible that CHEVIN LIGHT is free and CHEVIN PRO LIGHT is licensed and paid. Could someone throw some light on this point.

Comment: On g-types's site they have a Chevin Std and a Chevin Pro, BOTH of which are paid. I see no reference to a free version. The easiest would be to contact the foundry directly and ask, but most likely you need to buy a licence from them to be able to use it.

Comment: The fontsgeek website makes no mention of a licence. Even after downloading the zip, there is no licence included, so therefore I would assume it's probably an illegal download. The Pro version will have additional features for professional use compared to the standard version.  As I said, find the official font foundry if you want the right font, and the right information from the horses mouth.

Comment: by the way, real/legal fonts come with licence documentation - even Open Source fonts come with licence documentation . . . so beware!

Comment: I really appreciate your help everyone. I think that Chevin light is actually Chevin Std light. And that is a licensed font, for which I will buy a license.

Comment: @BillyKerr I do not know, but out of curiosity I want to know that is that possible that two fonts could be identical or share some point of resemblance.

Comment: Of course it's "possible" - like Helvetica and Arial - they are almost identical, but not quite.